# Distance sensor

Tags: arduino-due

I am adding a distance sensor to existing project that uses Arduino due, do I connect the trigger pin and the echo pin of the HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor directly to  Arduino due which uses 3.3V   while HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor uses 5V or do I need to use a voltage divider?

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about the thickness sensor?

Comment: Reading the datasheet for the sensor will get you the output voltage range of the sensor.

Comment: @user17339 Thank you for adding information about what sensor you were writing about.

Comment: @Avamander I was just advising OP to read the sensor datasheet.

Comment: @ChetanBhargava I mixed up the @.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in previous answers, you can directly use a Due output to drive the HC-SR04's Trig pin; according to the HC-SR04 spec sheet, that pin operates at TTL levels.  It will see 0 V as a 0-input and will see 3.3 V as a 1-input since it exceeds 2.4 V.  Also see  [3.3v input to Arduino digital pin](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/58498) in electronics.stackexchange.

However, the Due's inputs are not 5 V tolerant, so you will need to use a voltage divider between the Echo pin and a Due input.  See second paragraph of arduino.cc's [ArduinoBoardDue](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue) article:

> Warning: Unlike most Arduino boards, the Arduino Due board runs at 3.3V. The maximum voltage that the I/O pins can tolerate is 3.3V. Applying voltages higher than 3.3V to any I/O pin could damage the board.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on the sensor itself. Some sensors run on both 5V and 3.3V. There's a similar question here on StackExchange: [How to connect 5V sensors to 3.3V digital input (Due)?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/795/how-to-connect-5v-sensors-to-3-3v-digital-input-due)

But, in short, if the sensor can't operate in 3.3V, you'll need a level converter /shifter.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger pin is an input, so you can connect that directly to the Due.

The echo pin will however output 5v. You could use a voltage divider to bring that down to 3.3v or a bit lower.